# How can I have persistent typedarray in clojurescript

Tags: clojurescript

As I know, (js/Uint8Array.) is mutable, and converting a persistent vector to js-typedarray is effcient-lost.

Comment: If you're doing something so perf-sensitive that you need a `Uint8Array`, then you probably can't afford the overhead of persistent data structures. Otherwise, it's not clear what you're asking here.

Comment: hi jared, maybe I don't make it clear. I need the persistent typed-array for webgl stuff. The only way I know is to play with the persistent vector and then convert it to js/typedarray when submitting to GPU, which is low-effcient.

Comment: So you want to use clojurescript functions to manipulate a vector, then convert it for WebGL? Because if that's what you want, you will always have to eat a conversion step. Unless you just mutate a JavaScript typedarray the whole way.

Comment: Yeah, I just want the typedarray keeps immutable as the persistent-vector does.

Comment: AFAIK, that cannot be done. Immutability has its cost. Rich Hickey did some epic work to make that cost acceptable for most cases, but it's not zero. Or do you just want strong typing on the vector?